# What's the wireguard "key" exactly used for?

Tags: wireguard

In here, it is required to actually share your Wireguard public key to be able to port forward:

https://mullvad.net/en/help/port-forwarding-and-mullvad/

So if this key is actually used for encryption, why would Mullvad need to specifically only know it to port forward (wouldn't the public key get exchanged anyway in the initial handshake)?

And wouldn't this also imply no forward secrecy?

I assume this key here isn't used exactly for encryption, but then, what is this key used for?

Answer (score 1):

First, it makes sense to understand exactly *which* key they're referring to.

From that page:

> If you are using WireGuard protocol then you have to select the public WireGuard key that you are using with Mullvad on the machine you will forward the port to (see instructions below).
>
> ...
>
> In the Windows/macOS standalone WireGuard apps you can see it as the "Interface: Public key" on the server configuration.

So what they're asking for is the interface public key.

Wireguard doesn't strictly use the client/server model, where you configure a VPN server on a specific port and then have a VPN client connect to it. Instead, Wireguard uses what they call "interfaces" and "peers". A peer connects to a remote interface. Rather than having an interface be a whole VPN server on its own, Wireguard runs as a single service that can have many interfaces. Each interface is configured to allow a set of peers to connect to it. This allows for both traditional client/server style setups, and more peer-to-peer arrangements.

An interface's public key identifies it. If you connect to Wireguard on a remote system, it's not like connecting to a traditional OpenVPN server, where there's just one VPN operating at that endpoint. Instead, the interface's public key is used to identify *which* interface you want to talk to.

The request for the Wireguard interface public key is so they can identify which interface the port forwarding needs to be set up for.